# Convert 1200 to 1.2K in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I think there is a method within ruby or rails that does this but I can't remember where to find it or how to search for it, so I was hoping stackoverflow's collective wisdom might help.
I don't mind writing a method to do this, but I'm sure someone has a better solution.

Comment: I don't know of any ruby functions that will make that sort of conversion. You're probably better off writing your own function to do it for you. Don't forget to check your boundary conditions!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
number_to_human(1200, :format => '%n%u', :units => { :thousand => 'K' })

# 1200 => 1.2K
```

Answer (score 17):

If your number happens to be `1223` the accepted answer output would be `1.22K`, include the `precision` parameter to reduce this to `1.2K`. Also, if your number could be a wide range of numbers in the millions and billions, then best to cater for these also:

```
number_to_human(1200, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => { :thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B' })
# => "1.2K"

number_to_human(1223, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => { :thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B' })
# => "1.2K" 

number_to_human(1223456789, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => { :thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B' })
# => "1.2B"
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Rails Number Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html), 
The method **`number_to_human_size`** might be what you need.